# How to validate cloned fields in codigniter validation?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

In my application users can make their own fields list for adding products.here is my form.

```
<div class="row productsdiv">
    <input type="text" name="product[]" class="product form-control" <?php echo   set_value('product[]'); ?>'>
    <?php echo form_error('product[]'); ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id[]" <?php set_value("");?>>
     <input type="text" name="price[]" class="price form-control"<?php echo set_value("price[]");?> placeholder='<?php echo lang('placeholder_price'); ?>'>
     <?php echo form_error('price[]'); ?>
     <input type="text" name="qty[]" class="quantity form-control"<?php echo set_value("qty[]");?>'>
     <?php echo form_error('qty[]'); ?>
     </span><span class="total">0</span>
     <textarea name="description[]" cols="40" rows="3" class="footerinput form-control"></textarea>
     <?php echo form_error('description[]'); ?>
</div><!--Product row end -->
```

the above div products is cloned using a button add more .
my jquery

```
 $('#addmore').on('click', function() {      
     var cloneRow = $('.productsdiv:first').clone();
     cloneRow.find("input").val("").end();
     cloneRow.find(".total").text("").end();
     cloneRow.find(".total").after('<button type="button" class="close lebel-danger" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>');
     cloneRow.find(".footerinput").css({"display":"none"});
     cloneRow.appendTo('#products');
```

my controller:

```
if($_POST){
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_id', $this->lang->line('validation_name_label'),   'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('date',$this->lang->line('validation_date_label'), 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('product[]', $this->lang->line('validation_product_label'), 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price[]',$this->lang->line('validation_price_label'), 'required|is_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('qty[]',$this->lang->line('validation_quantity_label'), 'required|is_numeric');

//remaing logic here after.....
```

My problem is when the validation fails, I lose the newly added form fields when the page reloads. How can I send back form errors to each respected form field and still keep all their work when the form validation fails?
i am sorry if i am not clear.please comment for any further information if need.

Comment: There is no extra field increment limitation ?

Comment: no you can add as many as u can .
or if it's not good .please suggest any other way.
thanks for replay

Comment: what kind of validation do you need? I mean do you want to display an error message under a specific field or just want to show error on top or bottom of the form?

Comment: i want to display my errors under each field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery_validator library on the client side to display error for each field :

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

And in the other side (server side) all you can do is a global validation :

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('product[]', 'lang:product', 'trim|required');
```

Comment: still i lost may cloned field .

Comment: $('form.formValidate').validationEngine();  and add class attribute to your fields : <input class="validate[required] .." ...

Comment: how to validate fields that don't have id .through jquery

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your form creation more dynamical, that means: Put your  into a loop. Something like:

```
 $countProducts = 1;

 if ($this->input->post("submit", TRUE)) {
    $countProducts = $this->input->post("product", TRUE);
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $countProducts; $i++){

echo "<div class='row productsdiv'>";

echo  "<input type='text' name='product[" . $i . "]' class='product form-control'" .  set_value("product[" . $i . "]");

// echo the other items

echo "</div>";
}
```

To make form creation and validation more easy, have a look at the Form Generation Library http://frankmichel.com/formgenlib/user_guide/installation/install.html

Comment: in this case how my controller would look like.
as you are defining new name for the fields 'name='product[" . $i . "]''

Comment: The same way: Iterate over the array. But as said, give the Form Generation Library a try, it's very easy and also does the validation. Another point: Put the logic into the controller and use the view just for the output, not for creating.